# Image column null if not update image codeigniter Php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update firstname,lastname,image in codeigniter,But whenever i update only
first_name and last_name(not image) then image column become null in mysql,Where i am wrong
Here is my code

Here is my model

```
$add_data['first_name'] = ($this->input->post('first_name') && !empty($this->input->post('first_name'))) ? $this->input->post('first_name') : NULL;     
$add_data['last_name'] = ($this->input->post('last_name') && !empty($this->input->post('last_name'))) ? $this->input->post('last_name') : NULL;     

$saveArr = [];
    if(!empty($this->input->post('first_name'))){
       $saveArr['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
    }
    if(!empty($this->input->post('last_name'))){
       $saveArr['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
    }   
if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        $saveArr['image'] = $_FILES['image'];
    }
    else
    {
        $filename=time().uniqid(rand()).$_FILES['image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $filename);
        $saveArr['image']=$filename;
    }
$this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
$query=$this->db->update('users',  $saveArr);
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. You're most likely trying to read from a non existing array value. Without errors/supressed errors that turns into null. Always check if a value exists. `array_key_exists('image', $_FILES)` etc...

Comment: here no need to put `$saveArr['image'] = $_FILES['image'];` in this code `if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        $saveArr['image'] = $_FILES['image'];
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both condition you set `$saveArr['image']`, you just need to set `$saveArr['image']` when upload new image. so just remove line  `$saveArr['image'] = $_FILES['image'];`

Use below updated code.

```
 $add_data['first_name'] = ($this->input->post('first_name') && !empty($this->input->post('first_name'))) ? $this->input->post('first_name') : NULL;     
    $add_data['last_name'] = ($this->input->post('last_name') && !empty($this->input->post('last_name'))) ? $this->input->post('last_name') : NULL;     

    $saveArr = [];
        if(!empty($this->input->post('first_name'))){
           $saveArr['first_name'] = $this->input->post('first_name');
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('last_name'))){
           $saveArr['last_name'] = $this->input->post('last_name');
        }   
    if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
        {

        }
        else
        {
            $filename=time().uniqid(rand()).$_FILES['image']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "images/" . $filename);
            $saveArr['image']=$filename;
        }
    $this->db->where('id',$add_data['user_id']);
    $query=$this->db->update('users',  $saveArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand (I don't do PHP or CodeIgniter) your code always specifies the image column so it will always be updated.  You need logic that will *only* update that column if you have a value.